# update action of a RESTful route in Rails (PATCH or PUT)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I am a newbie to Ruby on Rails.why is the update action of a RESTful route in Rails is mapped to two HTTP verbs i.e, PATCH and PUT?

```
   PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
   PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
```

Which Method among the two is called when I update a resource(general CRUD )?

Comment: Both of these methods can be used for update. But `patch` is prefered when you want to update partial resource. `put` - update complete resource representation.

Answer (score 9):

It's done to follow **HTTP** standard for request types.

How @Mikhail mentioned, conceptually:

- `PATCH` is a proper request type, when you want to update only part of
  your object
- `PUT` is a standard way when you like fully overwrite your object with
  new data

While in Rails both of this can be easily done with single `update` action and the difference is just in passed `params`, then **Rails** makes two routes to cover standards, but there is no real need in making 2 different controller action for that.

As I know **Rails** uses `PUT` as default, but you can use any of them. Just follow mentioned conceptual rule

Comment: Tkachov, Thanks for your answer.I dug into this and i am not sure but read PATCH is going to be the primary method for updates in Rails 4.0.

Comment: Maybe you are right. Haven't checked this. It would be great if mark my answer as correct for future searches unless you need anything else in it

Comment: But PUT doesn't null out missing fields?

Comment: No, Rails doesn't do anything like that. It would cause a lot of bugs and missunderstanding

Comment: Can you please share the reference for "Rails uses `PUT` as default"? It'd be quite helpful to support that. Thanks!

Comment: @ShailendraShukla Hey, sorry. I'm way out of the context of this question as it was 4.5 years ago